# integer arithmetic on pointers in C

Tags: c

Will the statement below calculate the length of the array???:

```
UART1_BUF[1] = (unsigned char)(lcl_ptr - (unsigned char *)&UART1_BUF[1]);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
unsigned char UART1_BUF[128];

void apple_Build_SetFIDTokenValues(void)
/* apple_Build_SetFIDTokenValues - 
 * 
 * This function builds the apple protocol StartIDPS() command.
 */
{
 unsigned char * lcl_ptr;
 UART1_BUF[0] = BT_START_OF_PACKET;
 UART1_BUF[1] = 0x00;

 //BundleSeedIDPrefToken    
 lcl_ptr = apple_Build_BundleSeedIDPrefToken(&UART1_BUF[1]);

 UART1_BUF[1] = (unsigned char)(lcl_ptr - (unsigned char *)&UART1_BUF[1]);
*lcl_ptr = apple_checksum((unsigned char *)UART1_BUF, UART1_BUF[1]);
 UART1_BUF[UART1_BUF[1]] = *lcl_ptr;
}

unsigned char * apple_Build_BundleSeedIDPrefToken(unsigned char *buf_ptr)
{
    *(buf_ptr++) = 0x0D; //length of BundleSeedIDPrefToken minus this byte
    *(buf_ptr++) = BundleSeedIDPref_Token_FID_TYPE;
    *(buf_ptr++) = BundleSeedIDPref_Token_FID_SUBTYPE;
    //BundleSeedIDString
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    *(buf_ptr++) = '0';
    return (buf_ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will give you the number of bytes added by the `apple_Build_BundleSeedIDPrefToken()` function.  (The total number of bytes that have been filled in the `UART_BUF[]` array is one more than that, because that statement won't count the byte at `UART_BUF[0]`.)

In general, subtracting two pointers of type `T *` into an array of elements of type `T` gives you the difference as the number of *elements* (rather than the number of bytes).  (The result is undefined if either of the two pointers do not point to either an element within the same array, or the element just past the last one.)  The result itself has a signed integer type, `ptrdiff_t`, which is defined in `<stddef.h>`.

However, here, both pointers are pointing into the same array of `unsigned char`, so each element is a byte by definition.

So, the expression `lcl_ptr - (unsigned char *)&UART1_BUF[1]` will give the number of bytes added by the function.  (Note that `&UART_BUF[1]` is of type `unsigned char *` already, so the cast inside the expression is unnecessary.)

That expression is then cast to `unsigned char`, which could in theory truncate the result, although it clearly doesn't in the above example.

---

I note that the code is a little odd, in that it assigns to `UART_BUF[1]` three times!

1. `UART1_BUF[1] = 0x00;` sets it to 0;
2. `lcl_ptr = apple_Build_BundleSeedIDPrefToken(&UART1_BUF[1]);` sets it to `0x0D` inside the called function;
3. `UART1_BUF[1] = (unsigned char)(lcl_ptr - (unsigned char *)&UART1_BUF[1]);` sets it to `0x0E`, as the function adds 14 bytes.

---

More generally, remember to be careful with pointer subtractions: expecting them to always give a number of bytes is a common mistake...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void)
{
    int array[4];
    int *start, *end;

    start = &array[1];
    end = &array[3];
    printf("Difference (as int *): %d\n", end - start);
    printf("Difference (as char *): %d\n", (char *)end - (char *)start);
    return 0;
}
```

gives (on a system where `sizeof(int)==4`):

```
Difference (as int *): 2
Difference (as char *): 8
```

Comment: That code is merely one tenth the real code. Was just checking on the pointer arithmetic. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, provided that the result fits in a byte - which, from the code sample, it will - and, by 'length of the array', you mean the number of bytes minus the packet header.

Comment: Note that the cast of `&UART1_BUF[1]` to `unsigned char *` is unnecessary - it already has that type.